# gsutil ls command not working due to ampersand in path

Tags: gsutil, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-shell

I couldn't able to get succeed after multiple tries to list out the contents available in path, because my folder name contains ampersand like below.

`gsutil ls -r gs://testing_purpose/U&T`

> It returns error like below
>   CommandException: One or more URLs matched no objects.
>
> 'T' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Your command shell is interpreting `&` as a control character, so your statement looks like this to the shell:

```
yourshell$ gsutil ls -r gs://testing_purpose/U
yourshell$ T
```

To fix those, you should quote the argument with the control character, like so:

`gsutil ls -r "gs://testing_purpose/U&T"`

Comment: I am executing this script in Google Cloud SDK shell. I tried these all methods even before, but it throwing back same error.... !

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Windows and Google Cloud SDK Shell was putting the path inside quotation marks *and* escaping the & character with ^. E.g.:

```
gsutil ls "gs://a ^& b"
```